# I am trying fetch the first 6 month record data from a table based on the creation Date and activity_day from source table

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

activity_day >= creation_date + interval 6 month

Not getting any data

Comment: Can you please post your code here ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking for first 6 months records with respect to creation_date, then you need to use between logic like activity_day >= creation_date and activity_day <= creation_date + interval 6 month